# Optimizing SQl Query with bunch of Unions and Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization

I have written a query to get Production Quantity for either 1st shift, 2nd shift, 3rd shift or all shifts - based on the passed parameters.

Shift timings are following:

```
1st: 06:00 - 14:00
2nd: 14:00 - 22:00
3rd: 22:00 - 06:00
```

My query looks like following:

```
// Param.1 = date start , Param.2 = date end , Param.3 = shift start time , Param.4 = shift end time
// Param.5 = 1 when ShiftStarttime < ShiftEndtime ( Param.1 = 2015-12-26T06:00:00,  param.2 = 2015-12-26T14:00:00, param.3 = 6 , param.4 = 10 )
// Param.5 = 2 when ShiftStarttime > ShiftEndtime ( Param.1 = 2015-12-26T22:00:00,  param.2 = 2015-12-27T06:00:00, param.3 = 22 , param.4 = 2 )
// Param.5 = 3 when all of the shifts ( Param.1 = 2015-12-26T06:00:00,  param.2 = 2015-12-27T06:00:00)

SELECT 

      B.Machine_NAME,
      C.Part_Name,     
      SUM(A.QT_CONFIRMED) QT_CONFIRMED,
      D.SCRAP_REASON

 FROM 
       CONFIRMATION A 

       INNER JOIN MACHINE B ON A.Machine_ID =B.Machine_ID  
       INNER JOIN PART C ON B.Part_ID = C.Part_ID
       LEFT JOIN SCRAP_REASON D ON A.SCRAP_REASON_ID =D.SCRAP_REASON_ID

WHERE

      '[Param.5]' = '1'
       AND (A.DT_CONFIRMATION BETWEEN '[Param.1]' AND '[Param.2]') AND ((DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) >= '[Param.3]') AND (DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) < '[Param.4]'))

GROUP BY

      B.Machine_NAME,
      C.Part_Name,
      D.SCRAP_REASON

UNION


SELECT 

      B.Machine_NAME,
      C.Part_Name,     
      SUM(A.QT_CONFIRMED) QT_CONFIRMED,
      D.SCRAP_REASON

 FROM 
       CONFIRMATION A 

       INNER JOIN MACHINE B ON A.Machine_ID =B.Machine_ID  
       INNER JOIN PART C ON B.Part_ID = C.Part_ID
       LEFT JOIN SCRAP_REASON D ON A.SCRAP_REASON_ID =D.SCRAP_REASON_ID


WHERE

      '[Param.5]' = '2'
       AND (A.DT_CONFIRMATION BETWEEN '[Param.1]' AND '[Param.2]') AND (DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) BETWEEN 22 AND 23 OR  DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) BETWEEN 0 and 5)

GROUP BY

      B.Machine_NAME,
      C.Part_Name,
      D.SCRAP_REASON

UNION


SELECT 

      B.Machine_NAME,
      C.Part_Name,     
      SUM(A.QT_CONFIRMED) QT_CONFIRMED,
      D.SCRAP_REASON

 FROM 
       CONFIRMATION A 

       INNER JOIN MACHINE B ON A.Machine_ID =B.Machine_ID  
       INNER JOIN PART C ON B.Part_ID = C.Part_ID
       LEFT JOIN SCRAP_REASON D ON A.SCRAP_REASON_ID =D.SCRAP_REASON_ID


WHERE

      '[Param.5]' = '3'
    AND (A.DT_CONFIRMATION BETWEEN '[Param.1]' AND '[Param.2]') 

GROUP BY

      B.Machine_NAME,
      C.Part_Name,
      D.SCRAP_REASON
```

So basically depending upon the shift start time and shift end time, only on eof the union of the query will be executed due to Param.5 parameter. Please have a look at COMMENT in the query to understand parameters.

This query runs fine and gives proper result but I'm sure that it can be optimized to run faster if somehow I can remove Union or can modify some part of it.

Does anyone has better idea to write this query in more optimal way? If yes, kindly do share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two queries appear to be identical except for the `WHERE` clauses, which are different.  Try connecting the two `WHERE` clauses into a single query using `OR`.  Note that I added `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` statement to make sure that duplicates still get removed (which the `UNION` operator was doing in your original query).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    B.Machine_NAME,
    C.Part_Name,     
    SUM(A.QT_CONFIRMED) QT_CONFIRMED,
    D.SCRAP_REASON
FROM 
    CONFIRMATION A
INNER JOIN MACHINE B ON A.Machine_ID = B.Machine_ID  
INNER JOIN PART C ON B.Part_ID = C.Part_ID
LEFT JOIN SCRAP_REASON D ON A.SCRAP_REASON_ID = D.SCRAP_REASON_ID
WHERE
    (
        '[Param.5]' = '1' AND
        (A.DT_CONFIRMATION BETWEEN '[Param.1]' AND '[Param.2]') AND
        (
            (DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) >= '[Param.3]') AND
            (DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) < '[Param.4]')
        )
    )
    OR
    (
         '[Param.5]' = '2' AND
         (A.DT_CONFIRMATION BETWEEN '[Param.1]' AND '[Param.2]') AND
         (
             DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) BETWEEN 22 AND 23 OR
             DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) BETWEEN 0 and 5
         )
    )
GROUP BY
    B.Machine_NAME,
    C.Part_Name,
    D.SCRAP_REASON
```

Answer (score 0):

The queries all have the same structure except for the `WHERE` clauses.  Hence, you can combine the conditions using `OR`:

```
 SELECT B.Machine_NAME,  C.Part_Name, SUM(A.QT_CONFIRMED) as QT_CONFIRMED,
        D.SCRAP_REASON
 FROM CONFIRMATION A INNER JOIN
      MACHINE B
      ON A.Machine_ID = B.Machine_ID INNER JOIN
      PART C
      ON B.Part_ID = C.Part_ID LEFT JOIN
      SCRAP_REASON D
      ON A.SCRAP_REASON_ID = D.SCRAP_REASON_ID
WHERE ('[Param.5]' = '1' AND
       (A.DT_CONFIRMATION BETWEEN '[Param.1]' AND '[Param.2]') AND 
       ((DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) >= '[Param.3]') AND 
        (DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) < '[Param.4]'))
      ) OR
      ('[Param.5]' = '2' AND
       (A.DT_CONFIRMATION BETWEEN '[Param.1]' AND '[Param.2]') AND 
       (DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) BETWEEN 22 AND 23 OR
        DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) BETWEEN 0 and 5)
      ) OR
      ('[Param.5]' = '3' AND (A.DT_CONFIRMATION BETWEEN '[Param.1]' AND '[Param.2]')
      );
```